# Кодировка HtmlUntil

Tags: java, htmlunit

Для парсинга сайта использую jsoup и HtmlUntil для нажатия кнопки на странице. Все нажимается и парсится, проблема в том, что выводятся "крякозябры", можно ли как-то установить кодировку `UTF-8` для адекватного вывода текста?

```java
package com.company;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSpan;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.util.logging.Level;

public class Parsing {
    public void connectFileTxt() throws Exception {
        String text = "";
        Document document;
        LogFactory.getFactory().setAttribute("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog");
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(Level.OFF);
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.commons.httpclient").setLevel(Level.OFF);
        WebClient client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
        client.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
        String url = "https://auto.ru/cars/new/group/mercedes/e_klasse/20743577/20886691/?grouping_id=tech_param_id%3D20743577%2Ccomplectation_id%3D21225392&sort=fresh_relevance_1-desc&geo_radius=200\n"; //ссылка на сайт
        final HtmlPage page = client.getPage(url);

        HtmlSpan clickContact = page.getFirstByXPath("//span[@class='Button__content']");
        clickContact.click();

        document = Jsoup.parse(page.asXml());
        //                    .userAgent("Chrome/4.0.249.0 Safari/532.5")
        //                    .referrer("http://www.google.com")
        //                    .get();

        if (document.title().equals("Ой!")) {
            System.out.println("Ой, снова вылезла капча");
        } else {
            Elements elements = document.getElementsByClass("CardGroupHeader-module__horisontalList");
            System.out.println(document.text());
            System.out.println();

            System.out.println(document.title());
            text = elements.text();
            System.out.println(text);
            System.out.println("Ready!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Читайте джавадоки! С помощью `jsoup` это можно сделать значительно проще:

```java
String url = "https://auto.ru/cars/new/group/mercedes/e_klasse/20743577/20886691/?grouping_id=tech_param_id%3D20743577%2Ccomplectation_id%3D21225392&sort=fresh_relevance_1-desc&geo_radius=200";

Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

System.out.println(document.toString());
```

Comment: На странице присутствует кнопка, которую следует нажать что-бы получить конкретный текст. С помощью Jsoup ее не нажать.

Comment: Скорее всего сам сайт не дает себя запарсить, стоит шифровка.